# inkscape causes permanent waiting cursor

Tags: linux, linux-mint, inkscape, mouse-cursor

I am running Inkscape 0.48.4 r9939 on Linux Mint 16 ("Petra") with Compiz as my window manager.

Whenever I open Inkscape, as soon as I click anywhere using the selection tool, the mouse cursor switches to the "waiting" cursor. It remains the "waiting" cursor until I restart the window manager, log out and then in, restart the computer, etc. Nothing else seems to have an effect. Even when I close Inkscape and/or switch to another window or desktop, the cursor remains in "waiting" form.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Edit: in response to comment from edvinas.me, when I start from terminal, there are no warnings or messages of any kind, either when I first start or when I perform the first action that causes the waiting cursor.

Comment: Could you start it from terminal and add the output to your question?

Comment: I have the same problem using `Inkscape 0.91 r13725 (Apr  4 2015)` on ArchLinux. I'd say, this is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I may suggest you download the latest *stable* version from the app's site, since I assume you downloaded it from the default repos. If not, use the version that is in the repos or downgrade to a working version. By the way I'm using version **0.48.4-10** without any problems, you may want to install that version too.

Of course there may be steps to debug the app but looking for another build is far easier.

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully overcome the problem by installing 0.48.5 from [inkscape PPA](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-inkscape-0-48-5-on-ubuntu-linux-mint-pinguy-os-lxle-and-other-ubuntu-derivatives/) and then by switching off the option Peferences | Mouse | Use as tablet, which is turned on by default (or something similar at least, I have different language version). I firstly made the upgrade from PPA and I didn't check if this also fixes the problem on 0.48.4, so you can try it first.